# Script deleted by antivirus Html.Exploit getorgchart.js

Tags: getorgchart

Our server anti virus software is deleting your js file once a day:

{CAV}Html.Exploit.CVE_2014_0283-1 :
/getorgchart.js => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/getorgchart.js.251713992

Can you please look into this, I do not want to open doors on my site by adding an exception.

For our mygodirect.net domaine

You can contact me:
jorobidas@boomforex.net
jorobidas@gmail.com

Thanks.

Comment: this is normal if you are using the version with the watermark at the bottom right corner.

Comment: i'm using the non watermark version.